# String from MD5 Hash from known algorithm

Tags: hash, md5

I know String and Algorithm to generate MD5 hash value, Is it possible to get back the String from generated Hash.

Answer (score 1):

The very definition of a hash is a one-way, unique, encrypted value. Mathematically, consider it nearly impossible to get back the string generated from the hash.

Exceptions would be:

1. a vulnerability in the hashing algorithm (this happened with MD5, but its still difficult to crack it)
2. brute forcing (guessing) the string until you find a matching hash
3. using lookup tables of well-known phrases/words, and their associated hash values, eg: https://crackstation.net/

Comment: You mean to say brute force is the only way to figure out the string by actually generating hash and compare if two hash are equal. I am doing an exercise where I know part of string and algorithm which is generating hash, I have to figure out other part of string. Figuring other part of string by brute force seems impossible to me.

Comment: For any hashing algorithm, someone, somewhere, has intimate knowledge of the vulnerabilities and ways to chip away at it. So if you have these hints, it may be possible, however, just because the string "mystring" yields -> 01234567 does not mean "my" yields -> 01 and string yields -> "234567"... you'll may need to do a combination of brute force, guessing, to get where you need.

Answer (score 0):

No; hashing is, by definition,  a one-way process.

To derive the original string from the hash cannot be done without brute forcing different strings until one is found which generates an identical hash.

This process can take a very long time, though databases of known hashes exist which can speed up the process.

You should also know that two different strings can have the same hash.  This is called a hash collision.

Answer (score 0):

The MD5 is cryptographic hash function. It produces a 128-bit hash value. it is in text format of 32 digit hexadecimal number. **It is used to verify data integrity.**

No, you can not get actual value from hash value. I think you are looking for encryption and decryption mechanism.